# Its possible to apply a efect like pen and ink over an axis/path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, color

I dont know if a effect like using ink/pen transparency can be achieved in latex.
Something like the image, applyed to an axis or a path or any other object.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: In general, irregular shapes are more difficult than regular shapes.  Transparency is not a problem, even using images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My attempt is pretty simple, and I think the result is pretty much the same (maybe less smooth, I know). But it's probably easier as it is than trying a random path.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage   {pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset  {compat=1.17,axis on top}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  [
    clip=false,
    title = \bf{}Plot,
    xmin=-30, xmax=30,
    ymin=-100, ymax=300,
    axis lines=center,
    minor x tick num={9},
    minor y tick num={9},
    xlabel=X-Axis,
    ylabel=Y-Axis,
    legend style={anchor=south west,at={(0,.3)}},
    samples=50
  ]
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,300}
  {
    % Positive X-Axis
    \fill[pink!55] (14*rand+16,7*rand) circle (3pt);
    % Negative X-Axis
    \fill[blue!35] (-14*rand-16,7*rand) circle (3pt);
    % Positive Y-Axis
    \fill[green!35] (rand,140*rand+160) circle (3pt);
  }
  % Blue line
  \addplot[thick, blue] coordinates {(-15,-100) (25,300)};
  \addlegendentry{Line}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And my tikz:
[image]

Comment: Dont mind the smoothness , its a great option